# PHP/JQuery/JavaScript Countdown

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the jQuery Countdown (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-countdown/) to display a countdown to a specific date and time, but you need to program the number of days, hours, minutes, and seconds into the jQuery call.

I'm not quite sure how to do this in JS, but I figured using PHP to calculate the time and then having it plug those variables in would work. I found this PHP function online, but I'm unsure of the math to add a $seconds_left. Could someone please help?

```
function countdown($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute)
{
  // make a unix timestamp for the given date
  $the_countdown_date = mktime($hour, $minute, 0, $month, $day, $year, -1);

  // get current unix timestamp
  $today = time();

  $difference = $the_countdown_date - $today;
  if ($difference < 0) $difference = 0;

    global $days_left;
    global $hours_left;
    global $minutes_left;

  $days_left = floor($difference/60/60/24);
  $hours_left = floor(($difference - $days_left*60*60*24)/60/60);
  $minutes_left = floor(($difference - $days_left*60*60*24 - $hours_left*60*60)/60);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get seconds left by:

```
$seconds_left = floor($difference - $days_left*60*60*24 - $hours_left*60*60 - $minutes_left*60);
```

That *should* get you the seconds you're looking for (assuming the rest of the code works correctly, I'll admit I haven't tested this).